# Form for filters in Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a list of Link and I want to filter them by Category.

In my view I hard-coded a form with a select.

```
<form method="GET" action="{{ path('crm_links') }}">
    <input class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit"/>

    <select name="category" class="selectpicker pull-right" data-width="180" data-size="auto">
        <option value="0">Select a category</option>
        {% for category in categories %}
            <option value="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

Now in my controller I want to check for a "category" GET parameter.

And if it is > 0, I grap all link with this category id.

Do you know a cool way to do this ? Is it an appropriated way or it's not the symfony way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this FormFilterBundle : https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle, with a `filter_choice` type.

It's straightforward and easy to get started with.